# Issue writing first React application - Simple interactive form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

After an 8 year break from web dev I thought I'd try learning React. I started with this small interactive form that calculates the cost to run a Sodastream machine. All it does at the moment is add the cost of the 2 consumables (CO2 and Syrup) and calculate the cost per litre.

The issue I have is I can't find a way to get the running costs (Cost per Litre) into variables when the form inputs change. I tried to put the variables into the state array using the handleChange function, but at that point the other variables in the state array hadn't been updated yet.

I managed to produce a result just by doing the calculation at the end, but it's clunky and I can't really manipulate it. I Need to add further results like - consumption and payback time (if any payback at all ;) ).

Can someone tell me the correct way of doing this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-turing-s6k8zk?file=/src/App.js

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    consumablePrice1: "24.99", // Pounds
    consumableUnit1: "Litre", // Unit of measurment
    consumableUnitMakes1: "60", // Litres
    consumableCostToMakeOneLitre1: "0", // to be calculated

    consumablePrice2: "23.99", // Pounds
    consumableUnit2: "Litre", // Unit of measurment
    consumableUnitMakes2: "54", // Litres
    consumableCostToMakeOneLitre2: "0", // to be calculated
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of how to get what you're looking for
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-heisenberg-n46lww?file=/src/App.js

I did some changes to your code

1. Transform the calculation of the cost per litre into a function which receives the data to calculate via params

```js
const getCostPerLitre = (data) => {
  return toPounds(
    Number(
      costPerLitre(
        data?.consumablePrice1,
        data?.consumableUnit1,
        data?.consumableUnitMakes1
      )
    ) +
      Number(
        costPerLitre(
          data?.consumablePrice2,
          data?.consumableUnit2,
          data?.consumableUnitMakes2
        )
      )
  );
};
```

2. Then, I've added a new field for the calculation of the total price per litre to your state

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
  consumablePrice1: "24.99", // Pounds
  consumableUnit1: "Litre", // Unit of measurment
  consumableUnitMakes1: "60", // Litres
  consumableCostToMakeOneLitre1: "0", // to be calculated

  consumablePrice2: "23.99", // Pounds
  consumableUnit2: "Litre", // Unit of measurment
  consumableUnitMakes2: "54", // Litres
  consumableCostToMakeOneLitre2: "0", // to be calculated
    
  // This one
  costPerLitre: "£0.86" // to be calculated
});
```

3. Later, I've slightly modified your `handleChange` function, so that you storage in a constant the new state you was creating in the first instance, and then, I've used this data to call the previous defined function, to add the new value to the final new state.

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  // Update the values from the input
  const updatedValues = { ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };

  // Calculate the new cost based on the new values
  const newCost = getCostPerLitre(updatedValues);

  // Update the state object with the new values (including cost)
  setState({
    ...updatedValues,
    costPerLitre: newCost
  });
};
```

4. Lastly, I've used the new state defined value to show the proper value onto your page:

```js
<p className="result">
  Cost of Soda =&nbsp;{state.costPerLitre}
  &nbsp;per Litre
</p>
```

I hope this is useful for you.

By the way, I suggest you to use numeric type for numeric values on JSON (objects), since it will be better to transform a number to a string, rather than a string to a number.

Comment: @DMC With an upvote to my answer you can mark your question as resolved. I'm glad it was helpful for you! 

Comment: I did click the button, it look likes I'm too new to cast votes :D ------>

Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.